# Excel VBA - Move Columns depending on name without having a load of variables

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to organise my columns in some VBA code. I need them in a particular order depending on the value in Row A. I know i can do it using the following method but it's very long winded and looks horrible. Is there any more efficient way to do it?

Current Code

```
    Set Name = Cells.Find(What:="Name", LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

Then activate the cell, find column and then paste to where i want it. So if the columns went like this:

It would change the order to this

I can't just delete the columns that I don't want because they change position. So if i was to delete columns C:C it might delete what i need on occasion.

I need it so that no matter what columns are there, or how many, it will also go in the same order as shown above.

Thanks

Comment: Do the columns include formulas?  Or just data entry?  And what do you want to do with formulas that are not in your "new order" list?  Should the new list overwrite your old data; or should it be on a different sheet?

Comment: There are no formulas, it's just Raw data. The Columns that i don't need can just be overwritten or deleted. I just need the specific columns that are stated above, in that particular order. A custom sort?

Comment: As @pnuts suggested, you could easily code a custom sort for your problem.  And then you would know which columns to delete.  Record a macro while doing it; then clean it up. Post back if you have problems.

Comment: You say you want this based on what is in "row A", though I will assume you mean the value in Column A... but do you mean Row 1 as well?  Is there more to your code?  Seeing how you're setting variables is one thing, but we would need to see how they're used in your code to correct issues.  If the code is working as is, you might want to check out the Stack Exchange code optimization site, Code Review, found: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

If Range("A2").Value = "x" Then
    Range("A1,C1,D1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
End If
```